# Jquery Validation Plugin, get string of errors

Tags: jquery, string, validation

i want to get only the errror messages string,

```
('#frmEcard').validate({
        onkeyup: false,
        onfocusout: false,
        onsubmit: false,
        ignoreTitle: true,
        rules: {
            'txt_sendto': "multiEmails",
            'txt_subject': {
                maxlength: 255
            },
            'txt_message': {
                maxlength: 500
            }
        },

        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            $.jGrowl(HERE , {
                sticky:   true,
                life:    12000                    
            });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you go.

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            $.jGrowl($(error).text(), {
                sticky:   true,
                life:    12000                    
            });
        }
```

Comment: thats what i would do. If not, set a variable to ('#frmEcard').validate() and then loop through the errors object and pull your messages out. Use firebug to see what it looks like.

Comment: Awesome plug-in, but always seems to takes a lot of my time to configure :)